# How to name the branch of the Lambert W function?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, terminology, computer-algebra-systems

The Lambert W function has two real branches: the principal branch and the secondary real branch: the former is denoted by $W_0$ or $W$, the latter by $W_{-1}$. How do we name them ?

For example, we can write:
"Consider the solution $y = exp(-2 W(-x/2))$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function". In this case, the principal branch is implicitly assumed, so the issue is silently discarded. What can we write for the secondary case ?
"Consider the solution $y = exp(-2 W_{-1}(-x/2))$ where $W_{-1}$ is ..."

Comment: I think that *upper branch* for $W_0$ and *lower branch* for $W_{-1}$ are standard names.

Comment: "... where $W_{-1}$ is the lower branch Lambert W function" is correct ?

Comment: As you yourself have done, I too call $\mathrm{W}_{-1}(x)$ the secondary real branch.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still confused. Do you call $W_{-1}(x)$ the secondary real branch of the Lambert W function ? May I regard the branch itself as a function ?
Let assume that the reader may not know a lot on (very) special functions.

Comment: Each branch where the Lambert W function is real is a function. Note that the inverse of the function $f(x) = x\mathrm{e}^x$ for all real $x$ is only a relation. Identifying the branch point between the two real branches occurs at $x=-1/\mathrm{e}$ leads to the two real branches for the Lambert W function - the principal branch $\mathrm{W}_0(x)$ and the secondary real branch $\mathrm{W}_{-1}(x)$ of the Lambert W function.